# How to add a new object to an array in Mongoose?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, nosql

I keep getting the following error when I push a new comment document into a story collection in Mongoose:

```
{ 
[MongoError: The field 'comments' must be an array but is of type Object in document {_id: ObjectId('55d2429477da83b6f593ce53')}]
  name: 'MongoError',
  message: 'The field \'comments\' must be an array but is of type Object in document {_id: ObjectId(\'55d2429477da83b6f593ce53\')}',
  driver: true,
  index: 0,
  code: 16837,
  errmsg: 'The field \'comments\' must be an array but is of type Object in document {_id: ObjectId(\'55d2429477da83b6f593ce53\')}' 
}
```

This is my model:

```
var commentSchema = new Schema({
    text: String,
    date: { type: Date, default: Date.now },
    author: String  
})
var storySchema = new Schema({
    title: String,
    link: String,
    comments: [commentSchema],
    author: String,
    date: { type: Date, default: Date.now }
});
```

This is my query:

```
app.post('/news/:id/comment', function(req, res) {
    console.log('Hi Received');
    var comment = {
        "author": 'Steven',
        "text": req.body.comment
    }
    Story.findOne({_id: req.params.id}, function(err, data) {
        if(err) throw err;
        data.comments.push(comment);
        data.save(function(err, data){
            if (err) console.log(err);
            console.log(data);
        });
    })
});
```

I've tried Googling the solution but still can't fix the error.

Edit:

The collection that I want to add to currently looks like this:

```
> db.stories.find().pretty()
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("55d2429477da83b6f593ce53"),
    "author" : "Steven Chen",
    "link" : "AS",
    "title" : "AS",
    "date" : ISODate("2015-08-17T20:22:44.271Z"),
    "comments" : {
         "author" : "Steven",
         "text" : "Alsawdksada"
    },
    "__v" : 0
}
```

Comment: Your collection doc doesn't match your schema. Just like the error message says, `comments` is an object, not an array.

Answer (score 3):

Instead of using `findOne`, try using `findOneAndUpdate` with the `$addToSet` operator (http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.findOneAndUpdate).

It would look something like:

```
Story.findOneAndUpdate(
    {_id: req.params.id}, 
    {$addToSet: {comments: comment}}, 
    function(err,data) { 
       if(err) throw err; 
    }
)
```

Comment: Tried and it still returns the same similar error:
`MongoError: exception: Cannot apply $addToSet to a non-array field.    Field named 'comments' has a non-array type Object in the document _id: ObjectId('55d2429477da83b6f593ce53')`

Comment: After your update - your comments schema looks like it is a single object instead of a list. Try adding another set of curly braces around `{ "author" : "Steven", "text" : "Alsawdksada" }`

Comment: I updated with what the current collection looks like in Mongo

Comment: I think I know what the problem is. It probably has to do with the way I initially inserted the data. This is how I did it:
`for (var x = 0; x < Object.keys(req.body).length; x++) {
story['title'] = req.body['title'];
story['link']  = req.body['link'];
story['comments'].text = req.body['comments'];
story['comments'].author = 'Steven';

story['author'] = 'Steven Chen';
`

Comment: yep! try to start with empty comments and then use your post method and everything should be fine.

Answer (score 0):

You should have inserted the first entry in "comments' field wrong.
As this is an array you must push the object in comment array . It seems  you directly assigned the comment object to "comments" field  while inserting first comment.
Please check the same and it will be reolved